# Help text for asp:FileUpload or input:file

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I would like to know whether [this](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/labelify/) is possible with input:file

URL: http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/labelify/

Regards,
naveenj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a input button/text pointing to a hidden file input. A rough example would be like:

```
<input type="button" value="Filessssss" onclick="this.nextElementSibling.click();">
<input type="file" style="visibility:hidden;display:absolute;" onchange="this.previousElementSibling.value=this.files[0].name">
```

Then you can apply `labelify` on the button or text.
(tested on Chrome)

Comment: great solution...not working in IE6 though...  UPDATE: then again... who really cares if its working in IE6?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. There is no simple way that you can style input:file. You need to use a different file upload mechanism - either a flash based one, or one using the new HTML5 features.